# J48 partykit access flat list

Tags: r, party

I would like to access individual nodes in the flat list representation of the `party` object. That is, I would like to get a node, its split and kids and any other properties. I am new to `partykit` (just started exploring) so not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
require("partykit")
require("RWeka")
data("PimaIndiansDiabetes", package = "mlbench")
j48 <- J48(diabetes ~ ., data=PimaIndiansDiabetes)
j48_party <- as.party(j48)
j48_party_list <- as.list(j48_party)
j48_party_list[1:3]
## Error: length(i) == 1 & is.numeric(i) is not TRUE
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `partykit` there is only an `as.list()` method for `partynode` objects but not for the whole `party` object. The former contains only a recursive list node IDs, variable IDs, splits, etc. All the actual variable names, data, fitted values, etc. are not stored in the `partynode` but the `party`.

Therefore, the `as.list(j48_party)` does not actually produce the flat list but it returns the `j48_party` objects "as is" because it is internally a list (containing the `node`, `data`, `fitted`, `terms`, etc.).

So the flat list can only be produced for `as.list(j48_party$node)` but I guess that this will not have the information you are looking for. Possibly, `nodeapply()` will help you to get what you want...or some of the other examples in the vignettes.

Comment: thanks. vignette("constparty", package = "partykit") is pretty useful!